# How can I provide more context information when using ngx.log()?

Tags: lua, openresty

I would like to provide structured logging for our OpenResty application. We are aiming to implement MDC (Mapped Diagnostic Context) or something very similar.

Currently, calling `ngx.log(ngx.NOTICE, "foo")` gives something like this:

```
2019/01/31 17:39:50 [notice] 16#16: *1 [lua] example_logging.lua:20: myfunc(): foo, client: 172.17.0.1, server: _, request: "GET /example HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8080"
```

That is, logging automatically adds the key/value pairs for:

- server
- client
- request
- host

Is there a mechanism that allows more key/value pairs to be added to this without modifying the calls to `ngx.log()` but instead inject the required data elsewhere?

The application is using OpenResty 1.11.2.1-2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that it is not possible. `ngx.log` is just a tiny wrapper ([[1](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module/blob/576a10d246daf81c0ce1b959c50ee807769c01a8/src/ngx_http_lua_log.c#L34)](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module/blob/576a10d246daf81c0ce1b959c50ee807769c01a8/src/ngx_http_lua_log.c#L34), [[2](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module/blob/576a10d246daf81c0ce1b959c50ee807769c01a8/src/ngx_http_lua_log.c#L90)](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module/blob/576a10d246daf81c0ce1b959c50ee807769c01a8/src/ngx_http_lua_log.c#L90)) for [`ngx_log_error`](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/extending/api/logging/) with hardcoded message format, and `ngx_log_error` format is not configurable either.

[Old but still relevant comment from OpenResty core developer](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/openresty-en/oBJ4acgAIGM):

> Well, ngx.log() is for error logging. And it just invokes nginx core's
>   error logger, which does not support custom format, unlike the access
>   logging.